# CI/CD build failed with go -ldflags

Tags: go

Docker image: `golang:1.12.1`.
Local Go version: go1.10.4 linux/amd64.

I have such command in my `bash` script:

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags '-s -w -X main.Version=$(git describe --tags)' -o ./path/to/binary ./main.go &&
```

Now CI/CD fails on this command, but a month ago everything was ok with the same Docker image.

Is `-ldflags` deprecated or what?

Console output:

```
# command-line-arguments
usage: link [options] main.o
  ... //skipped
  -extldflags flags
        pass flags to external linker
  ... //skipped
  -s    disable symbol table
  ... //skipped
  -w    disable DWARF generation
```

and there is nothing about `-ldflags`.

Should I use `-extldflags` now?

I've tried

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o ./path/to/binary -ldflags '-s -w -X main.Version=$(git describe --tags)' ./main.go &&
```

, didn't helped.

---

#### Edit 1

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags '-s -w' -o ./path/to/binary ./main.go &&
```

was succesfull, but I need that parameter anyway.
Even

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags '-s -w -X main.Version=123456' -o ./path/to/binary ./main.go &&
```

works.

Investigating further in git output.

Comment: "Now CI/CD fails on this command" You should provide the actual error message.

Comment: @Volker I have provided it. Please, see "Console output". That was all from CI/CD

Comment: Is it only with CI? Can you reproduce the same issue locally with the same docker container? Without the container? There have been some recent tweaks to ldflags (see https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29096) but they should definitely still work

Comment: @EliBendersky sure, it even fails as a plain terminal command

Comment: What go version for local? For me `go build -ldflags '-s -w'` definitely works (just on some random program) with go1.12 linux/amd64

Comment: @EliBendersky go1.10.4 linux/amd64, I'll try to update go version

Comment: Weird, but doesn't work locally with 1.12 for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with single quotes around `ldflags`:

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags '-s -w -X main.Version=$(git describe --tags)' -o ./path/to/binary ./main.go &&
                                          ^                                            ^
                                          |                                            |
```

I went to double quotes and it worked:

```sh
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-s -w -X main.Version=$(git describe --tags)" -o ./path/to/binary ./main.go &&
                                          ^                                            ^
                                          |                                            |
```